# Forward parameters to jsp from servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Is there a way to send parameters from servlet to jsp without redirecting the browser to that page?

```
RequestDispatcher disp = request.getRequestDispatcher("shoppingCart.jsp");
disp.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: put the value in session scope and get that value in any jsp page

Comment: u just did it. set attribute to request before disp.forward(req,res). Access it from request(within the JSP you are forwarding to) using req.getAttribute(..); FYI request dispatcher doesn't sends response to web browser(watch your url when you do dispatch, it dosn't changes); hence no redirect .. CHEERS !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can either set the attributes(used in case of internal communication with servlets or servlet to jsp or vice-versa) to the response object and forward the request you can achieve this as :

```
      request.setAttribute("someKey","someValue");
```

You can also use the session scope to share the attributes between servlet and jsp like this:

```
     Http session = request.getSession();
     session.setAttribute("someKey","someValue");
```

Answer (score 2):

There can be one way as below:

```
RequestDispatcher disp = request.getRequestDispatcher("shoppingCart.jsp"+"?myParam=myValue");
    disp.forward(request, response);
```

If you are fine with "GET" method then you can solve this problem with appended parameters.

Comment: Worth mentioning you would want to url encode the parameters if you have any special characters :)